# How to prevent empty space when fading in/out div to avoid momentary site collapse

Tags: jquery, height, fadein, fade, fadeout

I am using a script to allow the user to alternate between view modes (Grid, List, and Full). When the user changes view modes, the active view fades out and the selected fades in. During that transition, there is empty space and as my site is responsive I do not want to set a fixed max-height to the content.

As you can see from the following, the footer jumps up when you switch view modes..

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/12/

Does anyone now a method to set a new max-height for the content each time the view mode is set? (Thereby avoiding the momentary negative space and adjusting to the height of the active content?)

HTML:

```
 <ul class="tabs js-view-mode">
      <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#grid">Grid</a></li>
      <li><a href="#full">Full</a></li>
    </ul>

    <section id="viewMode" class="content">
      <div id="list">here is list mode content</div>
      <div id="grid">here is grid mode content</div>
      <div id="full">here is full mode content</div>
    </section>

<footer></footer>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var wrap = $('#viewMode'),
      viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' );
  wrap.children().hide();

  $('.js-view-mode').on( 'click', 'a',function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this),
        type = t.attr('href');

   wrap.children().fadeOut(); $(type).delay(500).fadeIn();

    viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode', type );

  });

  if ( viewMode ) {
    $('.js-view-mode a[href='+ viewMode +']').trigger('click');
  } else {
    $('.js-view-mode li:first a').trigger( 'click' );
  }

});
```

CSS (for demonstrative purposes):

```
footer {background: red; display: block; width: 100%; height: 5px}

#list {height: 20px; width: 100%;display: block}
#grid {height: 55px; width: 100%;display: block}
#full {height: 100px; width: 100%;display: block}

/*.content {THIS NEEDS TO BE SET TO THE ACTIVE VIEWMODE CONTENT HEIGHT} */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a working exemple   http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/17/

the modif is :

```
 var lheight = $("#viewMode").height();
      if(lheight != 0){
   $("#viewMode").css("height",lheight+"px");         
      }
      wrap.children().fadeOut(); $(type).delay(500).fadeIn(function(){
          $("#viewMode").css("height","auto");
      });
```

I have taken the height of the div (you can get rid of the poor `!= 0` test, it's only to prevent the modification for the first display). Before changing the kind of view, I force the height of the div. In the `fadeIn` callback, I set the div's height to auto...

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work perfectly on the jsfiddle, but on my local wordpress it is just doing the same thing.. It doesn't add height: auto or change with the view selections. What do you think?

Comment: Would it matter that I began the script with jQuery.noConflict(); ? That's the only difference I can note

Comment: Give it a try. You can also use your browser debugger to show css properties of your div. check if the 'height' attributes is back to 'auto'. You can also do `.css("height","");` to remove the height attribute.

Comment: I did and the script actually is breaking completely. This is the working script without the feature I am trying for..

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9ae3T/20/

Comment: What is the error message in the debugger ? can you inspect the div to see its css properties ?

Comment: Yes...
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new b.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'cookie' viewmode.js:3
(anonymous function) viewmode.js:3
c jquery.min.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.min.js:4
q

Comment: Can we continue it in the chat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31111/discussion-between-n-ws-and-tchdvlp)